# How do I configure project properties using TortoiseSVN GUI to get the ignore list from a text file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN GUI. When I open a project's properties I am present with grid of two columns "Property" and "Value". I select "svn:ignore" for the property. In the Value I can enter multiple text strings separated by newlines.

How can I tell it to pull the ignore list from a text file? Is this possible in the properties popup dialog form, or is this only possible using command line tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties dialog you can see the `Import` option where you can specify a `.svnprop` file to import the properties from. Also, you can double click on a particular property or select `Edit` or `New` and hit load to similarly load the properties from a file.

If on the other hand you want a way of getting the ignore list from a file, like it is done in Git or Hg ( throught `.gitignore` and `.hgignore` ), you can't really do that with SVN / TortoiseSVN.